# Como referenciar métodos que usam array como objeto no console?

Tags: java, método

Eu tenho uma classe com os seguintes atributos e construtor:

```
private Person[] persons;
private int personCount;

public PersonDatabase(int defaultPersonsCapacity){

    persons = new Person[defaultPersonsCapacity];
    personCount = 0;
}
```

Seus métodos são os seguintes:

```
public void addPerson(String name, String surname, int age){

    if(personCount == persons.length){

        System.out.println("Unable to add Person.");
        return;
    }

    persons[personCount] = new Person(name, surname, age);
    personCount++;

    System.out.println("Person added.");
}

public int getPersonCount() {
    return personCount;
}
```

Outro é este:

```
public Person searchPerson (String name, String surname){
    for (Person p: persons) {
        if (p.getName().equals(name)&&p.getSurname().equals(surname)) return 
        p;
    }
    return  null;
}
```

A classe, atributos, construtor e primeiro método já estavam montados (é um exercício), e eu criei o segundo método. A classe `Person` que está nos atributos, possui apenas *setters* e *getters* dos atributos `name` e `surname`.

Eu criei os seguintes objetos na classe `Main`:

```
Person []persons=new Person[3];
    persons[0] = new Person("Jorge", "X");
    persons[1] = new Person("João", "Y");
    persons[2] = new Person("Maria", "Z");
```

Minhas perguntas são as seguintes:

1. Meu terceiro método (o "searchPerson") está correto?
2. Como posso referenciar o primeiro e o segundo método? Vou precisar do "Scanner"?
3. Independente da resposta, poderiam me dar detalhes de como fazer isso?

Eu já pesquisei bastante sobre isso, mas infelizmente, não encontrei nada satisfatório, e estou com dificuldades para entender a função desses métodos. Fiquei emperrado na referência dos métodos.

Comment: Não é caso para usar um `ArrayList` ? Você está complicando sem motivo aparente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, seu segundo método está ok, ele vai retornar a pessoa que coincidir o `name`e `surname`. 
Referente a como você pode inicializar o primeiro e o segundo método, não entendi bem o seu ponto, mas se é que estou pensando, você quer saber como alimentar o AddPerson, é isso? 
Se sim, você pode fazer chamando ele na sua classe `Main`, por exemplo, ao invés de fazer isso:

```
Person []persons=new Person[3];
persons[0] = new Person("Jorge", "X");
persons[1] = new Person("João", "Y");
persons[2] = new Person("Maria", "Z");
```

Você faz isso:

```
addPerson("Jorge", "X", 20);
addPerson("João", "Y", 20);
addPerson("Maria", "Z", 20);
```

Não se esqueça de chamar antes do `PersonDatabase(3);` para setar o tamanho do seu array.

Depois você pode usar o `searchPerson` da seguinte maneira:

```
Person pessoa = searchPerson("João", "Y");
```

Acredito que baseado em seus métodos, sua classe ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public class Exemplo {
    private static Person[] persons;
    private static int personCount;

    public static void PersonDatabase(int defaultPersonsCapacity) {

        persons = new Person[defaultPersonsCapacity];
        personCount = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonDatabase(3);

        addPerson("Jorge", "X", 20);
        addPerson("João", "Y", 20);
        addPerson("Maria", "Z", 20);

        Person pessoa = searchPerson("João", "Y");
        System.out.println(pessoa.getName() + " | " + pessoa.getSurname());
        pessoa = searchPerson("Jorge", "X");
        System.out.println(pessoa.getName() + " | " + pessoa.getSurname());
    }

    public static void addPerson(String name, String surname, int age) {

        if (personCount == persons.length) {

            System.out.println("Unable to add Person.");
            return;
        }

        persons[personCount] = new Person(name, surname, age);
        personCount++;

        System.out.println("Person added.");
    }

    public int getPersonCount() {
        return personCount;
    }

    public static Person searchPerson(String name, String surname) {
        for (Person p : persons) {
            if (p.getName().equals(name) && p.getSurname().equals(surname))
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Meu segundo método está correto?

É difícil responder sua pergunta. Ela fala em segundo método, mas nem dá para saber de qual está falando. Olhando para sua pergunta o segundo método é o `addPerson()` , mas a resposta aceita fala do `searchPerson()` que é o terceiro método.

Na verdade nem se sabe se todos estão na mesma classe, é apenas provável.

Como foi dito tem problemas em não usar uma lista e para usar um *array* deveria fazer um mecanismo mais sofisticado, mas vamos desta forma. Provavelmente nem deveria ser uma lista pelo pouco que se viu na pergunta, outra estrutura baseada em árvore provavelmente seria melhor. Qualquer exercício que ensine fazer errado é um exercício ruim.

O que você chama de [atributo na verdade se chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

O segundo método está correto, mas provavelmente não deveria ser feito assim, ou pelo menos não deveria ser a única opção. Geralmente é mais adequado criar a pessoa fora dele e passar o objeto criado e não parâmetros para o banco de dados criar. Está vinculando o detalhe da criação da pessoa com o banco de dados, desta forma torna o código pouco flexível e poderá ter problemas no futuro.

Se está falando do terceiro método, parece estar correto apesar de mal formatado. Pelo menos é o que parece, não tem que afirmar isso sem saber exatamente o que ele deve fazer, sem saber todos os requisitos, que não forma colocados na pergunta.

> Como posso inicializar o primeiro e o segundo método? Vou precisar do "Scanner"?

Não existe isso de inicializar método, é um termo que você inventou e só você sabe o que isto quer dizer.

Só você pode dizer se precisará de um `Scanner`. Desenvolver software não é seguir receitas de bolo, é entender o problema e colocar a melhor solução para ele. A pergunta não define bem qual é o problema, por isso é complicado dizer o que é o certo a fazer. Qualquer resposta que tente dizer isso está errada por definição, ela faz suposições para dar uma resposta.

É mais complicado responder quando na verdade nem sabemos a estrutura exata da classe,. Seria muito melhor ter colocado a classe toda. Quando você quer saber se a organização do código está certa fica complicado responder sem ver todo ele.

> Independente da resposta, poderiam me dar detalhes de como fazer isso?

Isso é considerado muito amplo para podermos responder, na verdade o mais correto é fechar a pergunta por causa disso.

O que eu posso dizer é que tem diversos erros conceituais neste código, mas nem sei quais dão para consertar porque ele tem requisitos artificiais, mais um motivo para não dar para responder adequadamente. Aconteça o que acontecer aprenderá errado com este exercício.

Além da classe `Person` que não posso falar muito (e só porque ela não foi postada eu não mostro meu código funcionando), você deveria ter a sua classe atual, vou reproduzir ela completamente aqui porque a resposta aceita fez ela deixar de ser uma classe útil e mistura as coisas. além de ter erros básicos de codificação:

```
class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonDatabase db = new PersonDatabase(3);
        //se quiser aqui colcoa um Scanner para pegar os dados e usá-los no lugar de literais
        db.addPerson("Jorge", "X", 20);
        db.addPerson("João", "Y", 20);
        db.addPerson("Maria", "Z", 20);
        Person pessoa = searchPerson("João", "Y");
        if (pessoa == null) return;
        System.out.println(pessoa.getName() + " | " + pessoa.getSurname());
        pessoa = searchPerson("Jorge", "X");
        if (pessoa == null) return;
        System.out.println(pessoa.getName() + " | " + pessoa.getSurname());
    }
}

class PersonDatabase {
    private static Person[] persons;
    private static int personCount;
    public PersonDatabase(int defaultPersonsCapacity) {
        persons = new Person[defaultPersonsCapacity];
        personCount = 0;
    }
    public void addPerson(String name, String surname, int age) {
        if (personCount == persons.length) {
            System.out.println("Unable to add Person.");
            return;
        }
        persons[personCount] = new Person(name, surname, age);
        personCount++;
        System.out.println("Person added.");
    }
    public int getPersonCount() {
        return personCount;
    }
    public Person searchPerson(String name, String surname) {
        for (Person p : persons) {
            if (p.getName().equals(name) && p.getSurname().equals(surname))
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/PersonDatabase.java).

Eu sei, você não gostou da resposta, mas a pergunta também não é boa. Eu só respondi porque a resposta atual aceita também não é adequada, e entre ficar só ela dando a impressão errada e outra resposta que não diz muito mas indica o caminho correto, achei que era melhor responder. Eu sei que a maioria não vai gostar desta resposta porque hoje as pessoas querem receitas de bolo e não aprender desenvolver software da forma correta, mas é o correto a se fazer já que a pergunta não foi fechada antes.